# Why is `region` field needed for active storage on S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Today I tried rails 5.2.0.

It generated following file template when `rails new`ed.

```
# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
# amazon:
#   service: S3
#   access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
#   secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
#   region: us-east-1
#   bucket: your_own_bucket
```

Question:

- As far as I know, there is no region in S3 service. If so, what does this parameter field `region` mean in the realm of Active Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"there is no region in S3 service", that's incorrect.

Extracted from [Working with Amazon S3 Buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html), official docs.

> Amazon S3 creates buckets in a region you specify. You can choose any
>   AWS Region that is geographically close to you to optimize latency,
>   minimize costs, or address regulatory requirements. For example, if
>   you reside in Europe, you might find it advantageous to create buckets
>   in the EU (Ireland) or EU (Frankfurt) regions. For a list of Amazon S3
>   regions, see [Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) in the AWS General Reference.

Comment: OK, now I realized that: 1. S3 is a global(non-regional) service 2. any bucket created in S3 is a regional object.